# Duplicate ForeignKey when using inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relational-database

I have created these classes in order to generate the database model via EntityFramework 6 code-first approach:

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ResponsiblePersonId { get; set; }
}

public class Car: Vehicle {

    public int HorsePower { get; set; }

}

public class Bike: Vehicle {

    public int FrameSize { get; set; }

}

public class Organisation
{
    public Organisation()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
        Bikes = new List<Bikes>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }


    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public List<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
}
```

So far this seemed right for me. 
But unfortunately, the resulting table looks like this:

```
Id | ResponsiblePersonId | HorsePower | FrameSize | Discriminator | Organisation_Id | Organisation_Id1
```

Why is the Organisation ForeignKey being generated twice? I expected this table to only have one Organisation_Id column.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing EF isn't smart enough to merge the foreign keys. Why not specify the foreign key explicitly on Vehicle like you do for the person? I'm reasonably sure that would work.

Comment: I don't think I've seen EF used with inheritance like this before. I thought it was supposed to be a 1:1 map, one entity per table. I don't know enough to say if I'm right or wrong though. Maybe EF and inheritance is okay

Comment: Organisation_Id and Organisation_Id1 are being created because how else will you establish a connection between the cars/bikes and the organisation?

Comment: @AlexPaven: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow and see how this works out.

Comment: @Joe_DM inheritance works fine with EF, there's even multiple types: TPH/TPT/TPC each with slightly different characteristics. In code first not all may be possible, it's been a while since I tried. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways for EF to implement the physical tables for your inheritance hierarchy. The default one, the one you are using, is called Table Per Hierarchy (TPH). It uses only one table for all the derived entities, with one `Discriminator` column to specify the type of entity which is contained in the record. EF also adds to the table a column for each property that is included in any of the derived entities.

So as the relationship between the derived entities and `Organisation` is defined at child level (the lists of `Car` and `Bike` properties in `Organisation` entity) EF decides to create a separate column for each child entity type `Organisation_Id`, and you don't want that.

How to change this? There are several ways:

- Don't use TPH. Use instead TPC (Table Per Concrete class). That is, EF creates a separate table for each one of your child entities. How to do this: remove the `DbSet<Vehicle>` property from your `DbContext`. If this doesn't make it, set an explicit configuration for the physical table name for each entity derived from `Vehicle` like this:

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      ...
      modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Cars");
      modelBuilder.Entity<Bike>().ToTable("Bikes");
  }
  ```
- If you need to continue using TPH, I don't know of any way to implementing this that will generate only one `OrganisationId` column in the database and only one Foreign Key between `Vehicle` and `Organisation`. Common sense would say that you might define the `Organisation` foreign key at the `Vehicle` base entity level. But then you get errors when generating the migration:

  > Organisation: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'Organisation' is not
  >   valid. Type 'Car' of FromRole 'Organisation_Cars_Target' in
  >   AssociationType 'Organisation_Cars' must exactly match with the type
  >   'Vehicle' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

  It seems that when the relationship is defined at base level then EF expects  the lists in `Organisation` to be defined of type `Vehicle` and not `Car` or `Bike`. And this does not fit with your model.

  And if you try to define `OrganisationId` or `Organisation` properties in your derived classes then you get a different error when generating the migration, because you are not allowed to use the same name for the properties in the different child entities. You can use different names, but then you get two columns again. There is no way to get one column this way either.

  So if you stick with TPH, as far as I know, you have to put up with having two columns for your `OrganisationId`. At least you can name them in a more verbose way with some fluent configurations:

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      ...
      modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
          .HasMany(o => o.Bikes)
          .WithRequired()
          .Map(x => x.MapKey("OrganisationIdBike"));

      modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
          .HasMany(o => o.Cars)
          .WithRequired()
          .Map(x => x.MapKey("OrganisationIdCar"));
  }
  ```

I would recommend you to change to TPC, as with your model the fluent mappings are a bit less complex to write.

For a better understanding of TPH, TPC and TPT (Table Per Type, yet another implementation of inheritance hierarchies) read [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/04/14/tip-12-how-to-choose-an-inheritance-strategy/).