# Multiple inheritence makes duplicated columns on database and conflict occurred

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, orm

I have two class inherited from the same base class.  Here is part of the code:

```
public abstract class baseclass
{
    public virtual int? MyObjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Object MyObject { get; set; }
}
public class Derived1 :baseclass
{

}
public class Derived2 : baseclass
{

}
```

In database that makes 3 Column for same property:
MyObjectID 
MyObject_ID 
MyObject_ID1

So I can't send value to the database. It must be just one column: MyObjectID 
How can I prevent duplicated columns?

Comment: What does the above code have to do with a database? You are in complete control of what columns you add there.

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: It's codefirst project, and i use EF. I have to prevent duplicated columns in database

Comment: look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107363/duplicate-foreignkey-when-using-inheritance

Comment: There are differences, i didn't use one to many relationship. I have problem within base class not derived entities. (I have to use Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) in my project.). Let me try fluent configurations.

Comment: I tried but i can't use ".HasMany(o => o.MyObject)"

Comment: I suspect the columns do not map to the same property. my guess is that "MyObjectID" maps to the "MyObjectID" property, "MyObject_ID" is the FK for the navigation property "MyObject" (you didn't specify you wanted to use "MyObjectID" for this) and "MyObject_ID1 is the discriminator column for the TPH inheritance (of that I'm unsure though). However, note that the Object MyObject does not have a int PK (unless it's not System.Object) and can't be saved in a table without Key by EF.

Comment: @MesutTasci, setting the [Key] annotation to your  public virtual int? MyObjectID { get; set; } can solve this but that is IF you want your model that way. Derived classes can inherit from Base but can have another Id as well if needed.

Comment: P.S. Just so you know, you probably are looking for `Derived` not `Derivered`. But that's unlikely to be in your code so, probably ignore this.

Comment: thanks ErikE, I deleted "er".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Fluent Api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AnotherObject>().Ignore(o => o.Derived1);
modelBuilder.Entity<AnotherObject>().Ignore(o => o.Derived2);
modelBuilder.Entity<Object>().Ignore(o => o.AnotherObject);
```

And now I have another problem. I need to set one of baseclass property from Derived class.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string MutualString { get; set; }
}
public class Derived1 :BaseClass
{
    public virtual Object1 Kisi { get; set; }
    public override string MutualString
    {
        get { return Kisi.TamAd; } //*TamAd is string.
        set { value = Kisi.TamAd; }
    }
}
public class Derived2 : BaseClass
{
    public virtual Object2 Firma{ get; set; }
    public override string MutualString
    {
        get { return Firma.TamAd; }
        set { value = Firma.TamAd; }
    }
}
```

I got error when try to listing. "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" But it is not null